# Getting error "Unexpected Token" in HTML DOM script for a HTML form

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom

I'm developing an android app with phonegap. I'm trying to use an HTML form in one of the pages and I've been told that I should use HTML DOM. I've made the script but I got a error saying: Unexpected token.

Here's the sample code in HTML:

```
<form name="editNoteForm" id="formaltera" method="post" action="index.html">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="primeiroNome">Primeiro Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="primeiroNome" id="primeiroNome">
  </div>

  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="ultimoNome">Ultimo Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="ultimoNome" id="ultimoNome">
  </div>

  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="numeroTelefone">Telefone</label>
    <input type="number" name="numeroTelefone" id="numeroTelefone">
  </div>

  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Guardar">
  </div>
</form>
```

And here's the script I made so I can get something like the HTML code above.

```
<form name="formaltera" id="formaltera" method="post" action="index.html"></form>
    <script charset="utf-8" language="javascript">
    var temp1 = localStorage.getItem("selected");
    var temp = localStorage.getItem(temp1);

    temp = temp.split(";");
    var firstName = temp[0];
    var lastName = temp[1];
    var phoneNumber = temp[2];
    var form = document.getElementById('formaltera');
    var formBody = form.childNodes[0];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var inputTextA = document.createElement('input');
    var inputTextB = document.createElement('input');
    var inputTextC = document.createElement('input');
    var inputSubmit = document.createElement('input');
    var labelA = document.createElement('label');
    var labelB = document.createElement('label');
    var labelC = document.createElement('label');
    var labelTextA = document.createTextNode('Primeiro Nome');
    var labelTextB = document.createTextNode('Ultimo Nome');
    var labelTextC = document.createTextNode('Telefone');

    div.data-role = "fieldcontain";

    labelA.for = "primeiroNome"; //I'm getting an error in here
    labelB.for = "ultimoNome";
    labelC.for = "numeroTelefone";

    inputTextA.type = "text";
    inputTextA.name = "primeiroNome";
    inputTextA.id = "primeiroNome";
    inputTextA.value = firstName;

    inputTextB.type = "text";
    inputTextB.name = "ultimoNome";
    inputTextB.id = "ultimoNome";
    inputTextB.value = lastName;

    inputTextC.type = "number";
    inputTextC.name = "numeroTelefone";
    inputTextC.id = "numeroTelefone";
    inputTextC.value = phoneNumber;

    inputSubmit.type = "submit";
    inputSubmit.name = "submit";
    inputSubmit.id = "submit";
    inputSubmit.value = "Guardar";

    form.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(labelA);
    labelA.appendChild(labelTextA);
    div.appendChild(inputTextA);

    form.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(labelB);
    labelA.appendChild(labelTextB);
    div.appendChild(inputTextB);

    form.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(labelC);
    labelA.appendChild(labelTextC);
    div.appendChild(inputTextC);

    form.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(inputSubmit));


    </script>
```

The HTML code could be a bit different from the script I've made because I wrote it just to elucidate you. Thanks in advance. Hope I'm explaining myself well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `for` attribute should be assigned through `htmlFor` property

```
labelA.htmlFor = ...
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLLabelElement for further reference

Comment: Thank you. I think it has correctedthe error but now is given a error on ´div.data-role = "fieldcontain";´ saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment...". Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Use  `div["data-role"] = "fieldcontain";`

Comment: That div is supposed to show a grey line dividing the inputs. It's not giving me any error anymore but the line is not showing. By the way, thanks for the answer. Any thoughts about this? Thank you

Comment: I can't tell without an example and the css applied. this should be another question